# Anylogic: Traffic Stop Line Time Variable

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to make a simple intersection simulation. the idea is to register how much time take a car to get out of the intersecction. at the moment i tought of this:

1. Adding a startTime variable to the car Agent
2. In the "On Car Passed" register the time on a variable, and then make a simple substraction and add it to a Histogram Data

The issue is that i cannot add the time to the agent in the stopLine.

Anyone can help me with this?. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can but you have to do this little trick:

```
((Car)car).startTime=time();
```

Assuming that you car agent name is Car... if the name is AnotherName you will do:

```
((AnotherName)car).startTime=time();
```

It's just that the stopline variable car is of type Agent (or Object maybe, not sure) so you have to convert it to the car or agent type that you are using.

Comment: Thank you very much, if another car agent go through the same stopLine, should i add an if condition?

Comment: why would you need to do that?

Comment: beacuse i have two car-type agent (ex: "Bus" and "Car")

Comment: In that case what I would do is create a parent agent called Vehicle that holds the startTime value... so both bus and car are the same class :)